# S4G Currency Updater

Tags: multi-currency, currency, conversion

This app does not do what is expected. I've added currencies to the company profile, enabled Advanced Currency Management, entered the recommended Remote Site, and Authenticated myself as the User.

When I click "Run now and schedule" the message "Currency Updater is running" and nothing happens afterwards. The screen remains exactly as it was, and my currencies aren't updated. Further, there aren't even any logs to go explain the details of any errors. This doesn't work!

Can anyone tell me where things are going awry?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in that app caused by the change of Yahoo Finance API result format.

As far as I know the parser has been changed and the app is working fine now.

Upgrate to the last version (3.6). You would have to revoke the previous permissions manually and then re-authorise your user.

Comment: Martin,

Thank you. I noticed that it worked properly once, but I have yet to fully test it manually yet. I am upgraded to 3.6, and will test it Monday morning. Thanks again.